# Retrieving user posts

Tags: php, laravel

how can I pull all the posts of a certain user? should i foreach all the posts of a certain user? Like if user1 posted something and I want to pull out whatever he posted and only shows when he's logged in.

Comment: post the code you have tried please. My guess is that you are trying to retrieve from a DB?

Comment: can u clarify your questioning wherebouts..

Comment: Yes sorry I'm trying to retrieve data from the DB, I haven't yet tried anything just want to see any possible ways or samples if there are any around.

Comment: Laravel documentation provide examples of similar use cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, if you are using Eloquent relationships things would look something like this.

First, define your relationships within your models.  If you're following the example below, I'm going to assume the following.

> Your users table in database is named `users`.  Your posts table in
>   database is named `posts`, and has an integer column named `user_id`
>   corresponding to the id of the user the post belongs to.  If your
>   table and column names are different, make sure you read the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)
>   docs to learn how to set custom table names and column names for
>   Eloquent models.

**app/models/User.php**

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    // All the default User.php stuff....

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

}
```

**app/models/Post.php**

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

After we've defined those relationships, you can get a particular user using something like this.

```
$user = User::find(1); // This will get the user with an ID of one.
```

Then, you retrieve that user's posts, we can use the Eloquent relationship we defined earlier.

```
$posts = $user->posts()->all();
```

If the user is already logged in, you can user the `Auth` class to do this for the logged in user.

```
$posts = Auth::user()->posts()->all();
```

You'll now realize that `->posts()` actually returns a Collection, and you can use all of the Query and Eloquent methods on that collection as normal.

Comment: Thanks Sajan that helps a lot :).